# Extreme difference comparing directory size vs. used diskspace

Tags: windows, disk-space

On a Windows Server 2019 Enterprise, we have a disk with just one directory.

When we check the properties of the directory, the summary of file sizes is more than twice the amount of diskspace used (see picture)
When we do a "dir /s" on this directory, the numbers are about the same.

What's wrong with the directory properties dialog?
No symbolic links or directory shortcuts...

[Size comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URGRh.png)

Comment: Probably related to the massive number of file and folders? You have hundreds of thousands of files and folders in there. Why the size used on disk is *smaller* than the actual folders though, I have no idea. I thought this would be the other way around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the folder size (in properties) different from the total file/folder sizes in the folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/567175/why-is-the-folder-size-in-properties-different-from-the-total-file-folder-size)

Comment: I feel this is not a duplicate, as what is happening here is the *other way around* compared to the linked question. The individual folders are showing up as consuming far *more* space than the disk itself shows, not *less*. I think a symbolic link to another volume may have found its way into the folder somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> No symbolic links

Are you sure about that? With *this* many files and folders buried, you might very well have a symbolic link somewhere.

[You can run this command in a command prompt to find out:](https://superuser.com/a/496155/440147)

```
dir /AL /S C:\
```

I cannot see any other reason for the contents of a folder to be *bigger* than the drive space itself. Normally it would be the other way around with this many files.